# How do I save my chilli plant

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, plant-recommendations, chili

I was away for a couple of days and I guess the weather was hot here, so when I came back my chilli plant had dried up, picture below. I have watered it now, but the plant hasn't perked up. The branches and stem are still alive, I checked. Does anyone know what I should do to save my plant? Are the leaves dead, should I remove them? This is my first chilli plant. Any advice is welcome. Thanks for the answers in advance. [image]

Comment: "This is my first chilli plant" - Correction: This *was* your first chilli plant. It looks dead as a doornail. It's hard to believe it got into that state in just "a couple of days" with no water!

Comment: I agree, how many days was it?

Answer (score -1):

you may "save it" by planting the seeds of your chilli fruit.

Comment: please be so kind and tell me why I got a down vote?

Comment: I down voted because the answer didn't seem to answer the question. To me it seems like something that should be a comment or expounded upon to state why the plant can't be revived and how to plant the chili seeds.